# bitwise operations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
- (void)pushDigitalJoin: (NSString*)joinNumber
{       
    char joinByteArray[] = {
        0x05, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x27
    };

    int joinIntNumber = ([joinNumber intValue] - 1);
    char *upperByte;
    char *lowerByte;

    NSString *decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 0xff];

    *upperByte = joinIntNumber & [decimalString intValue];
    *lowerByte = joinIntNumber >> 8;


     joinByteArray[7]= *upperByte;
     joinByteArray[8] = *lowerByte;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(joinByteArray); i++) {

        NSLog(@"joinByteArray: position-%i | value-%i",i,joinByteArray[i]);
    }

 }
```

basically i have the byte array
i need to change the last 2 bytes based on the "joinNumber"
then add those 2 bytes to the array

however i get compile errors on the joinIntNumber >> 8 and the operation above that which uses the and operator doesnt seem to work.  (output always shows 39)

so how do i correctly use these bitwise operators and get my 2bytes added to the array?

CHANGES MADE TO REFLECT COMMENTS AND SHOW OUTPUT (ANSWER(:

```
   - (void)pushDigitalJoin: (NSString*)joinNumber
{       
    char joinByteArray[] = {
        0x05, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00
    };

    int joinIntNumber = ([joinNumber intValue] - 1);
    char upperByte = nil;
    char lowerByte = nil;

   // NSString *decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 0xff];

    upperByte = joinIntNumber & 0xff;//[decimalString intValue];
    lowerByte = joinIntNumber >> 8;


    joinByteArray[7]= upperByte;
    joinByteArray[8] = lowerByte;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(joinByteArray); i++) {

        NSLog(@"joinByteArray: position-%i | value-%x",i,joinByteArray[i]);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT (joinnumber = 5):

```
2011-08-26 11:06:07.554 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-0 | value-5
2011-08-26 11:06:07.555 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-1 | value-0
2011-08-26 11:06:07.557 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-2 | value-6
2011-08-26 11:06:07.558 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-3 | value-0
2011-08-26 11:06:07.559 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-4 | value-0
2011-08-26 11:06:07.561 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-5 | value-3
2011-08-26 11:06:07.562 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-6 | value-27
2011-08-26 11:06:07.563 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-7 | value-4
2011-08-26 11:06:07.564 Cameleon[2213:40b] joinByteArray: position-8 | value-0
```

Comment: upperByte and lowerByte will need initialising before dereferencing them

Comment: +1 @Dave F, but probably the OP just wants to take all of those *s out... Those don't need to be pointers at all.

Comment: if it do :   char *upperByte = nil; the app crashes with bad_access on that line.  also i though & was the dereferencer so where a i dereferencing

Comment: As Carl says, you don't need them to be pointers at all, so just change char* lowerByte to char lowerByte. and *lowerByte just becomes lowerByte in the assignment further down.

Comment: Remove the `*` from the declarations/uses of `upperByte` and `lowerByte`.

Comment: made changes but still getting the 39.  need to read answer below

Comment: The reason why you are getting 39 is because that his decimal for hex 0x27. You are attempting to append 2 more char to your array of size 7 and since it is not crashing for you, you are dangerously overwriting on memory outside of your array. [See my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207114/bitwise-operations/7207487#7207487).

Comment: `&` is very much not “the dereferencer”. It is, in fact, the opposite of the dereference operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so how do i correctly use these bitwise operators and get my 2bytes added to the array?

You don't. The array is declared on the stack and has fixed size (7 bytes). If you try to add values onto the end, you'll wind up stomping on other values on the stack and probably corrupting the stack.

Unrelated, but also problematic is this:

```
NSString *decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 0xff];

*upperByte = joinIntNumber & [decimalString intValue];
```

That really doesn't make any sense... why are you creating a string from an int only to take it's intValue? It'd be better to write:

```
*upperByte = joinIntNumber & 0xff;
```

And another thing... you're declaring upperByte and lowerByte as character pointes (char*), but you don't set them to point at anything in particular. So when you try to set the characters that they point to as in the above line, you're going to end up putting the values into random places.

If you want a C array that you can modify, you should declare one that's large enough to hold any values that you're going to add, in this case:

```
char joinByteArray[] = {
    0x05, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00
};
```

You could also create it on the heap with malloc() and friends, but again you'd need to make it large enough at the outset to hold your extra values, or else grow the array as necessary with realloc() before adding your new values. In any case, **don't write past the end of your array.**

Comment: as for the stringwithformat thing, originally i had what u said todo but changed it in order to try and see if it would work this way.  as for the array, its the only way i could get my tcp socket to properly output the hex code to the server.  is this why no matter what value i feed to the joinnumber i always get 39 in my output???

Comment: thank you. i have to run some more testing but i believe it working now.

Comment: @Caleb the 39 is decimal for hex 0x27 which is just the last entry in the array of 7.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: `joinByteArray` is only 7-elements long, so you can't assign to indices 7 and 8. Not sure what you're trying to do here.  Is this array supposed to grow over time as you receive more numbers?  If so, you're better off using a `NSMutableArray` or `NSMutableData` and storing that in an instance variable:

```
char initialBytes[] = {
    0x05, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x27
};
NSMutableData *joinBytes = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:initialBytes length:7];
```

Second problem: you declare `upperByte` and `lowerByte` as pointers, but they should just be stack-allocated variables.  Or better yet, use an array for this to make appending the data easier later on:

```
char newBytes[2];
newBytes[0] = joinIntNumber & 0xff;
newBytes[1] = joinIntNumber >> 8;
```

Once you've got that, you can append to the data:

```
[joinBytes appendBytes:newBytes length:2];
```

I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do, but you may want to consider endianess (see, for example, [`NSSwapHostIntToBig`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003774)).

Comment: Worth noting that you still cannot safely assign to indexes 7 and 8 of a 7-byte NSMutableData without first increasing the NSMutableData's length.

Answer (score 0):

This may be closer to what you are looking for.

```
- (void)pushDigitalJoin: (NSString*)joinNumber
{       
    //You are appending 2 more values so you need to specify
    //that jointByteArray is 9
    unsigned char joinByteArray[9] = {
        0x05, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x27
    };

    int joinIntNumber = ([joinNumber intValue] - 1);

    //Upper and lower byte do not need to be char*
    //unless you want to needlessly malloc memory for them
    char upperByte;
    char lowerByte;

    //0xff is an int (unsigned) so this is useless
    //NSString *decimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 0xff];

    //To get upper byte you need to know the size of int
    //use int32_t to specify >> 24 so you don't need to use sizeof
    upperByte = joinIntNumber >> ((sizeof(joinIntNumber) - 1) * 8);
    lowerByte = joinIntNumber & 0xFF;

    joinByteArray[7] = upperByte;
    joinByteArray[8] = lowerByte;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(joinByteArray); i++) {
    //Should log hex since you are manipulating bytes
        NSLog(@"joinByteArray: position-%X | value-%X",i,joinByteArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to declare upperByte or lowerByte at all and could do direct assignment into `joinByteArray`.