# NSString Binary manipulation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `NSString *a =@"00011"` and `NSString *b=@"110001"`, I want to do **bitwise AND (&)** using these string , That is **"a"** & **"b"** , the value should be  `00001`.

 How to achieve that, I can do manual manipulation like looping the strings, But I want to use & operator. How to achieve that?

Comment: Use the right data type for the job.  String is not the right data type.

Comment: You can't use a bitwise operator with a NSString.

Comment: Check with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207304/905514

Comment: @trojanfoe When the number of digits should not be constrained it's common to store numbers as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested Code :D

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  int a = [self binaryStringToInt:@"100011"];
  int b = [self binaryStringToInt:@"110001" ];
  int result = a & b;
  NSString *resultBinary = [self binaryStringFromNum:result];
  NSLog(@"%@", resultBinary);
}


-(int)binaryStringToInt:(NSString *)str {
  const char* utf8String = [str UTF8String];
  char* endPtr = NULL;
  int num = strtol(utf8String, &endPtr, 2);
  return num;
}

- (NSString *)binaryStringFromNum:(uint64_t)num {
  NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  for(uint64_t numberCopy = num; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>= 1)
  {
    [str insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By coincidence the binary representation of ASCII encoded "0" and "1" characters makes it possible to just perform bitwise-and on the characters themselves:

```
'0' & '0' == '0'
'0' & '1' == '0'
'1' & '0' == '0'
'1' & '1' == '1'
```

This fact makes it possible to easily perform bitwise and on arbitrary length strings (more than 64 digits). The following implementation uses UTF16 characters which work as well. It is constrained only by stack size (due to the VLA).

```
NSString *StringBinaryAnd(NSString *a, NSString *b)
{
    NSUInteger length = [a length];
    NSCParameterAssert([b length] == length);

    unichar buffer[length];
    [a getCharacters:buffer range:(NSRange){.length=length}];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 1)
        buffer[i] &= [b characterAtIndex:i]; // here's the magic

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:buffer length:length];
}
```